# How can I add a .cpp file to jni start in Buildozer?

Tags: python, c++, kivy, buildozer, python-for-android

I have project running with Buildozer and Python 3.11 but now I want to integrate some C++ code that I need to initialize during jni start.c (before PyInitialize call).

How can I add that code and then link jni with my other c++ code.